# Upper and lower bound on expected value of square of sum os independent random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Let $Y_1,\cdots,Y_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables. Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$. What is upper and lower bounds of $\mathbf{E}[X^2]$ in terms of first and second moment of $Y_i$'s?

One upper bound is

$$
\mathbf{E}\left[X^2\right]
   \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}\left[Y_i^2\right]
      + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}[Y_i]\right)^2.
$$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something dumb but because they're i.i.d. don't you just have $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{i,j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[Y_iY_j]=n\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2]+n(n-1)\mathbb{E}[Y_1]^2$?

Comment: @JasonGaitonde yes indeed. So stupid of me. I think the second term is incorrect in your comment. Thanks